# How can i pass arguments from my native code to flutter via intent?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, native

i am launching a specific route in flutter using **Intent** like below

```kotlin
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if(remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("route","/specific_route_name");
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

and my onGenerated function is responsible to handle and launch that flutter screen like below

```dart
static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage());
      case '/specific_route_name':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => SpecificPage());
      default:
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
```

now how can i pass data too? via that intent i tried **intent.putExtra("data")** & **intent.putExtra("argument")** (just tried my dumb luck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. you don't (need to). Simply encode everything into the root path.. like /specific_route_name?foo=bar and then use something like:

```dart
    final uri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
    final route = uri.path;
    final param = uri.queryParameters['foo'];
```

this way you will have your route name in `route` and can read out your parameters through `uri.queryParameters`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but yea i know that already; i kept this as my last choice, actually i need to pass a object which i can obviously stringify and pass as a query param. but i really wanted to know that if passing data using intent is possible

Comment: no..  not out of the box. But you can write a plugin which simply returns the Intent data.

Comment: huh! i think you're right, the amount of research i've done makes me believe that i have to come up with third party solution, thanks btw!